# How to recover the effective rights of a registry key? c++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, createfile

I would like to retrieve the effective rights of a given registry key as a parameter. I test with an existing registry key under Windows. To do that I use the methods CreateFile, GetSecurityInfo and GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA. 
I wanted to know if this is the correct method, because I have an error for the CreateFile method that returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. Moreover for the method GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA, I do not understand which parameter I must put in TRUSTEE_A?

```
LPCWSTR lpwRegistryKey = L"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\.acc\\OpenWithProgids\\WMP11.AssocFile.ADTS";
HANDLE handleKey;
handleKey = CreateFile(lpwRegistryKey, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARED_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);

if(handleKey == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
   //qDebug()<<"error";
}

//Here is an user SID
PSID pUserSid;
QString sSid("S-4-5-12");
BOOL resultSidConvert = ConvertStringSidToSidA(sSid.toStdString().c_str(), &pUserSid);
//Here success
if(resultSidConvert != 0)
{
    PACL pDacl;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptor;

    DWORD dwResultSecurity = GetSecurityInfo(handleKey, SE_REGISTRY_KEY, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nullptr, &pUserSid, &pDacl, nullptr, &pSecurityDescritptor);
    if(dwResultSecurity == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
       ACCESS_MASK pAccessMask;
       TRUSTEE_A pTrustee; //How should I initialize pTrustee?

       DWORD dwEffectiveRights = (GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA(pDacl, &pTrustee, &pAccessMask);
       if(dwEffectiveRights == ERROR_SUCCESS)
       {
           if((pAccessMask & DELETE) == DELETE)
           {
               qDebug()<<"Delete";
           }
           if((pAccessMask & GENERIC_READ) == GENERIC_READ)
           {
              qDebug()<<"READ";
           }
         //etc ..........
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think a registry key is a file ? Did you ever even looked at some documentation ? start here : https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry

Comment: The kernel has an `ObOpenObjectByName` routine that takes an optional object type and parse context, since creating and opening objects can take a complex set of parameters that varies based on type, and may need to be allowed to return a handle for a different type (e.g. opening a Device returns a handle for a File). There are various system calls that set things up to create or open a particular object type. For a Key, we use `NtCreateKey` and `NtOpenKeyEx`, or WINAPI `RegCreateKeyExW` and `RegOpenKeyExW`. For a Device, we use `NtCreateFile` and `NtOpenFile` or WINAPI `CreateFileW`.

Comment: @eryksun I am looking for the effective rights of a registry key to a user's SID.
Looking at the Windows document, I thought we had to use method CreateFile because GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA takes as handle parameter ...

Comment: You mean `GetSecurityInfo` takes a handle, not `GetEffectiveRightsFromAclW` (use Unicode, not ANSI). A handle is an opaque reference to an object, which may be an object in the kernel or some other system component. That said, we can skip opening a handle in this case by using [`GetNamedSecurityInfoW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getnamedsecurityinfow) with the path "CLASSES_ROOT\.acc\OpenWithProgids\WMP11.AssocFile.ADTS".

Comment: @eryksun excuse me I was wrong. Yes GetSecurityInfo takes a handle... If I understood what you mean, I have to use GetNamedSecurityInfoW and GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA ? if that's it, what should I put in the TRUSTEE_A parameter?

Comment: Whose access are you looking to check? The current user? Another user? A group?

Comment: @eryksun I want to check access for the current user

Comment: For the current user, if you need to check a specific set of rights that are all required, just try to [open the key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexw) with the rights in the desired access. If you need to get all rights for the current user, one approach is try to open a handle with `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` access and then call [`NtQueryObject` : `ObjectBasicInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntqueryobject) to get the handle's `GrantedAccess`.

Comment: @eryksun I just want to open a registry key and find out if the user has access to DELETE, GENERIC_READ ... That's why I wanted to use the GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA method.But I can not implement it

Comment: The call `RegOpenKeyExW` with the desired access. If it fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, then the current user doesn't have this right. It's far simpler, and even more reliable, than getting the security descriptor and implementing a manual access check.

Answer (score 0):

## A registry key is not a file!

Don't use CreateFile. Use RegOpenKeyEx instead.
First, you must run the application as admin.

Then, you can open the key successfully. After that, take a look at `RegGetKeySecurity` function.

Comment: can I use the GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA method ? Because I want to see the different rights that the current user can have

Comment: I think no. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-geteffectiverightsfromacla) can help you. RegGetKeySecurity is enough.

Comment: yes I saw this method but I do not understand how to use it after using RegGetKeySecurity.... do you have an example please ? 
If I understand it is necessary to use RegOpenKeyEx, RegGetKeySecurity, and  GetEffectiveRightsFromAclA but How to initialize TRUSTEE_A parameter ?

Comment: @Tom13000, `GetNamedSecurityInfoW` or `GetSecurityInfo` is preferred over the the older type-specific functions such as `GetFileSecurity`, `RegGetKeySecurity`, etc. Also, `GetEffectiveRightsFromAclW` ("W"; user names are Unicode) isn't reliable to check current-user access. It doesn't factor in resource policy (e.g. for files, read-attributes and delete access can be granted by the parent) and the calling context, including privileges, mandatory access control based on the caller's integrity level, and implicit owner rights (and the "OWNER_RIGHTS" SID).

Comment: @eryksun Thank you for your answer I found the solution to use the method GetEffectiveRightsFromAclW

Comment: @Tom13000, as I already said, `GetEffectiveRightsFromAclW` is really wrong to get the access of the current user. It's a best guess for another user or group, in general.